# How can you set conditional shipping price within WooCommerce for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to sell magazines through WooCommerce. When someone orders just one or two magazines then the shipping costs would be an x amount, however when someone orders more then two that would become a package and different shipping costs must be shown. Is this possible within WooCommerce, if so how?

Comment: No by default but there're some plugins out there for this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend this plugin ;-)
[WooCommerce Advanced Shipping](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-advanced-shipping/8634573)

There are others like [Table rate shipping](http://www.woothemes.com/products/table-rate-shipping-2/) (from WooThemes)